# HTML action=launch

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

tratando de hacer n boton que me descargue un audio sin que lo ejecute el navegador (que aun no lo he logrado), me encontre este codigo para hacer la descarga:

```
<input type="submit" class="BotonDown" value="Descargar" onclick="document.location.href='?action=launch&type=3&id_file=28360'">
```

pero no entiendo la parte del href='?action=launch&type=3&id_file=28360',
alguien podria explicarme este funcionamiento o donde encuentro informacion sobre el action=launch y su utilizacion

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo importante aquí es que el `document.location.href` va a llevarte a la URL que le asignes. Si no le pones un dominio (www.ejemplo.com) va a asumir que es la actual. Entonces lo que hace con `?` es pasarle parámetros por `GET` a la URL en la que lanzas el script.

Si ejecutas el script de abajo en la consola del navegador, se recargará la página actual y le va a agregar esos parámetros.

```
document.location.href='?action=launch&type=3&id_file=28360'
```

En este caso (es.stackoverflow.com) no va a hacer nada porque seguramente no haya nada que reciba esos parámetros, entonces va a quedar

`https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/290707/html-action-launch?action=launch&type=3&id_file=28360`

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero si tengo entendido de el paso por get a la url, mi duda es lo que sigue despues, ese action, el launch y que significa el tipe 3, que lenguaje es ese y la funcionalidad, creeria que es JS pero no he encontrado informacion sobre ello. gracias

Comment: Puede ser cualquier cosa, y cualquier lenguaje. Imagínate que son variables y valores. Así simplemente no significan nada. Para saber que significan realmente habría que ver el código al que apuntan realmente. Lo más probable es que las variables sean usadas en un código del lado del servidor, pero podría no ser así. Si forman parte de algún tipo de estándar, o algo así, es difícil saberlo, pero realmente no lo creo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aclaracion